# Query using $gte and New Date() working in MongoDB shell but not through python pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python

When I run the following in the mongodb shell, it returns the correct number of records:

*(searching for the matching "SourceName" within the last 8 days)*

```
mongos> db.fdl.count({ SourceName : "SRC1" , "Created" : { $gte : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-8))  }})
482
```

But when I try to run it through python / pymongo, it returns nothing:

```
import time
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://mylogin:mypass@mymongo.mydomain.net")
mydb = myclient['fdl']

print mydb.fdl.count({ SourceName : "SRC1" , "Created" : { $gte : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-8))  }})

myclient.close()
```

then run it:

```
python query.py
0
```

In the python code, if I run the query:

```
    print mydb.fdl.count({ SourceName : "SRC1" })
```

Then I do get a value. So the problem comes from the $gte search.

The problem is not with the count() method, because if I use the find() method, the problem is the same: documents returned in the MongoDB shell, but nothing when calling with python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: ,Welcome to the site? What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB pymongo documentation [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count)

The  [count()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) method is **`deprecated`** and not supported in a transaction. Please use [count_documents()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) instead.

**count(with_limit_and_skip=False)**

**DEPRECATED -** Get the size of the results set for this query.

The count() method is deprecated and not supported in a transaction. Returns the number of documents in the results set for this query. Does not take limit() and skip() into account by default - **`set with_limit_and_skip`** to True if that is the desired behavior. Raises OperationFailure on a database error.

When used with **`MongoDB >= 2.6`**, count() uses any hint() applied to the query. In the following example the hint is passed to the count command:

```
collection.find({‘field’: ‘value’}).hint(‘field_1’).count()
```

The count() method obeys the read_preference of the Collection instance on which find() was called.

Changed in version 3.7: Deprecated.
Changed in version 2.8: The [count()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) method now supports [hint()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.hint).

**count_documents(filter, session=None, kwargs)**

Count the number of documents in this collection.

The [count_documents()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) method is supported in a transaction.

All optional parameters should be passed as keyword arguments to this method. Valid options include:

- skip (int): The number of matching documents to skip before returning
  results.
- limit (int): The maximum number of documents to count.
- maxTimeMS (int): The maximum amount of time to allow this operation
  to run, in milliseconds.
- collation (optional): An instance of 
  [Collation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collation.html#pymongo.collation.Collation). This option is only supported on MongoDB 3.4 and
  above.
- hint (string or list of tuples): The index to use. Specify either the
  index name as a string or the index specification as a list of tuples
  (e.g. [(‘a’, pymongo.ASCENDING), (‘b’, pymongo.ASCENDING)]). This
  option is only supported on MongoDB 3.6 and above.

The count_documents() method obeys the [read_preference](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.read_preference) of this Collection.

Note When migrating from count() to count_documents() the following query operators must be replaced:

```
Operator     Replacement
$where        $expr
$near         $geoWithin with $center
$nearSphere $geoWithin with $centerSphere

$expr requires MongoDB 3.6+
```

For your further ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415514/in-mongodbs-pymongo-how-do-i-do-a-count) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

Comment: Hello Haidar. Thank you so much for responding to my question and sending detailed information. 

The problem is not in count vs. count_documents() because even if I use the " find" method, I still get no records. So the problem is either on the use of $gte or "New Date() ...".

Just to test, I replaced the query with

`print mydb.fdl.count_documents({ SourceName : "SRC1" , "Created" : { $gte : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-8))  }})`

And I am still getting 0 results. Whereas if I run the same query directly in the MongoDB shell, I get the correct number of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - timedelta(days=8)
print(mydb.fdl.count_documents({ SourceName : "SRC1" , "Created" : { $gte : dt } } }))
```

The above code (note the usage of `datetime` module) calculates the date for the query filter and gets the document count for the condition as per the question post:

> (searching for the matching "SourceName" within the last 8 days)